# Logstash breaking with recent renaming of JDBC mySQL connector

Tags: mysql, jdbc, logstash, connector

For some reason Logstash with the Elastic Stack X-Pack is breaking. I believe it's to do with the recent renaming of the mySQL connector, which hasn't been updated in the various config files. However, I can't find where the error file is originating in this error log. Additionally, if anyone knows how to rename the actual mySQL connector from com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver to com.mysql.jdbc.Driver this should fix everything.

Error Log:

```
C:\Program Files\logstash-6.3.2\bin>logstash -f sql.conf
Sending Logstash's logs to C:/Program Files/logstash-6.3.2/logs which is now configured via log4j2.properties
[2018-08-31T15:01:52,502][WARN ][logstash.config.source.multilocal] Ignoring the 'pipelines.yml' file because modules or command line options are specified
[2018-08-31T15:01:53,031][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Starting Logstash {"logstash.version"=>"6.3.2"}
[2018-08-31T15:01:55,217][INFO ][logstash.pipeline        ] Starting pipeline {:pipeline_id=>"main", "pipeline.workers"=>8, "pipeline.batch.size"=>125, "pipeline.batch.delay"=>50}
[2018-08-31T15:02:06,342][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Elasticsearch pool URLs updated {:changes=>{:removed=>[], :added=>[http://localhost:9200/]}}
[2018-08-31T15:02:06,342][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Running health check to see if an Elasticsearch connection is working {:healthcheck_url=>http://localhost:9200/, :path=>"/"}
[2018-08-31T15:02:06,539][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Restored connection to ES instance {:url=>"http://localhost:9200/"}
[2018-08-31T15:02:06,575][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] ES Output version determined {:es_version=>6}
[2018-08-31T15:02:06,592][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Detected a 6.x and above cluster: the `type` event field won't be used to determine the document _type {:es_version=>6}
[2018-08-31T15:02:06,609][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] New Elasticsearch output {:class=>"LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch", :hosts=>["//localhost:9200"]}
[2018-08-31T15:02:06,625][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Using mapping template from {:path=>nil}
[2018-08-31T15:02:06,659][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Attempting to install template {:manage_template=>{"template"=>"logstash-*", "version"=>60001, "settings"=>{"index.refresh_interval"=>"5s"}, "mappings"=>{"_default_"=>{"dynamic_templates"=>[{"message_field"=>{"path_match"=>"message", "match_mapping_type"=>"string", "mapping"=>{"type"=>"text", "norms"=>false}}}, {"string_fields"=>{"match"=>"*", "match_mapping_type"=>"string", "mapping"=>{"type"=>"text", "norms"=>false, "fields"=>{"keyword"=>{"type"=>"keyword", "ignore_above"=>256}}}}}], "properties"=>{"@timestamp"=>{"type"=>"date"}, "@version"=>{"type"=>"keyword"}, "geoip"=>{"dynamic"=>true, "properties"=>{"ip"=>{"type"=>"ip"}, "location"=>{"type"=>"geo_point"}, "latitude"=>{"type"=>"half_float"}, "longitude"=>{"type"=>"half_float"}}}}}}}}
[2018-08-31T15:02:06,909][INFO ][logstash.pipeline        ] Pipeline started successfully {:pipeline_id=>"main", :thread=>"#<Thread:0x598b8674 sleep>"}
[2018-08-31T15:02:06,996][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Pipelines running {:count=>1, :running_pipelines=>[:main], :non_running_pipelines=>[]}
[2018-08-31T15:02:07,359][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}
[2018-08-31T15:02:07,895][ERROR][logstash.inputs.jdbc     ] Unable to connect to database. Tried 1 times {:error_message=>"Java::JavaSql::SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Cannot load connection class because of underlying exception: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.WrongArgumentException: Failed to parse the host:port pair 'localhost:3306;user=test;password=test123;databaseName=test;integratedSecurity=true;'."}
[2018-08-31T15:02:07,916][ERROR][logstash.pipeline        ] A plugin had an unrecoverable error. Will restart this plugin.
  Pipeline_id:main
  Plugin: <LogStash::Inputs::Jdbc jdbc_connection_string=>"jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306;user=test;password=test123;databaseName=test;integratedSecurity=true;", jdbc_driver_class=>"com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver", jdbc_user=>"doesntmatterwithauthentication", statement=>"SELECT * FROM phones", id=>"de31f73d4505e1de7e76bce4917c48b412909473f3872288edd51acccf0e0be6", enable_metric=>true, codec=><LogStash::Codecs::Plain id=>"plain_ad3ad9d5-a3e8-492a-9231-1e729e8c4190", enable_metric=>true, charset=>"UTF-8">, jdbc_paging_enabled=>false, jdbc_page_size=>100000, jdbc_validate_connection=>false, jdbc_validation_timeout=>3600, jdbc_pool_timeout=>5, sql_log_level=>"info", connection_retry_attempts=>1, connection_retry_attempts_wait_time=>0.5, parameters=>{"sql_last_value"=>1970-01-01 01:00:00 +0100}, last_run_metadata_path=>"C:\\Users\\ross.massie/.logstash_jdbc_last_run", use_column_value=>false, tracking_column_type=>"numeric", clean_run=>false, record_last_run=>true, lowercase_column_names=>true>
  Error: Java::JavaSql::SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Cannot load connection class because of underlying exception: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.WrongArgumentException: Failed to parse the host:port pair 'localhost:3306;user=test;password=test123;databaseName=test;integratedSecurity=true;'.
  Exception: Sequel::DatabaseConnectionError
  Stack: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(com/mysql/cj/jdbc/exceptions/SQLError.java:110)
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(com/mysql/cj/jdbc/exceptions/SQLError.java:97)
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(com/mysql/cj/jdbc/exceptions/SQLError.java:89)
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(com/mysql/cj/jdbc/exceptions/SQLError.java:63)
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(com/mysql/cj/jdbc/exceptions/SQLError.java:73)
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(com/mysql/cj/jdbc/exceptions/SQLExceptionsMapping.java:79)
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(com/mysql/cj/jdbc/exceptions/SQLExceptionsMapping.java:131)
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(com/mysql/cj/jdbc/NonRegisteringDriver.java:227)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java/lang/reflect/Method)
org.jruby.javasupport.JavaMethod.invokeDirectWithExceptionHandling(org/jruby/javasupport/JavaMethod.java:423)
org.jruby.javasupport.JavaMethod.invokeDirect(org/jruby/javasupport/JavaMethod.java:290)
C_3a_.Program_20_Files.logstash_minus_6_dot_3_dot_2.vendor.bundle.jruby.$2_dot_3_dot_0.gems.sequel_minus_5_dot_10_dot_0.lib.sequel.adapters.jdbc.connect(C:/Program Files/logstash-6.3.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/sequel-5.10.0/lib/sequel/adapters/jdbc.rb:215)
C_3a_.Program_20_Files.logstash_minus_6_dot_3_dot_2.vendor.bundle.jruby.$2_dot_3_dot_0.gems.sequel_minus_5_dot_10_dot_0.lib.sequel.adapters.jdbc.RUBY$method$connect$0$__VARARGS__(C_3a_/Program_20_Files/logstash_minus_6_dot_3_dot_2/vendor/bundle/jruby/$2_dot_3_dot_0/gems/sequel_minus_5_dot_10_dot_0/lib/sequel/adapters/C:/Program Files/logstash-6.3.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/sequel-5.10.0/lib/sequel/adapters/jdbc.rb)
C_3a_.Program_20_Files.logstash_minus_6_dot_3_dot_2.vendor.bundle.jruby.$2_dot_3_dot_0.gems.sequel_minus_5_dot_10_dot_0.lib.sequel.connection_pool.make_new(C:/Program Files/logstash-6.3.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/sequel-5.10.0/lib/sequel/connection_pool.rb:127)
C_3a_.Program_20_Files.logstash_minus_6_dot_3_dot_2.vendor.bundle.jruby.$2_dot_3_dot_0.gems.sequel_minus_5_dot_10_dot_0.lib.sequel.connection_pool.RUBY$method$make_new$0$__VARARGS__(C_3a_/Program_20_Files/logstash_minus_6_dot_3_dot_2/vendor/bundle/jruby/$2_dot_3_dot_0/gems/sequel_minus_5_dot_10_dot_0/lib/sequel/C:/Program Files/logstash-6.3.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/sequel-5.10.0/lib/sequel/connection_pool.rb)
C_3a_.Program_20_Files.logstash_minus_6_dot_3_dot_2.vendor.bundle.jruby.$2_dot_3_dot_0.gems.sequel_minus_5_dot_10_dot_0.lib.sequel.connection_pool.threaded.assign_connection(C:/Program Files/logstash-6.3.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/sequel-5.10.0/lib/sequel/connection_pool/threaded.rb:206)
C_3a_.Program_20_Files.logstash_minus_6_dot_3_dot_2.vendor.bundle.jruby.$2_dot_3_dot_0.gems.sequel_minus_5_dot_10_dot_0.lib.sequel.connection_pool.threaded.RUBY$method$assign_connection$0$__VARARGS__(C_3a_/Program_20_Files/logstash_minus_6_dot_3_dot_2/vendor/bundle/jruby/$2_dot_3_dot_0/gems/sequel_minus_5_dot_10_dot_0/lib/sequel/connection_pool/C:/Program Files/logstash-6.3.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/sequel-5.10.0/lib/sequel/connection_pool/threaded.rb)
C_3a_.Program_20_Files.logstash_minus_6_dot_3_dot_2.vendor.bundle.jruby.$2_dot_3_dot_0.gems.sequel_minus_5_dot_10_dot_0.lib.sequel.connection_pool.threaded.acquire(C:/Program Files/logstash-6.3.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/sequel-5.10.0/lib/sequel/connection_pool/threaded.rb:138)
C_3a_.Program_20_Files.logstash_minus_6_dot_3_dot_2.vendor.bundle.jruby.$2_dot_3_dot_0.gems.sequel_minus_5_dot_10_dot_0.lib.sequel.connection_pool.threaded.RUBY$method$acquire$0$__VARARGS__(C_3a_/Program_20_Files/logstash_minus_6_dot_3_dot_2/vendor/bundle/jruby/$2_dot_3_dot_0/gems/sequel_minus_5_dot_10_dot_0/lib/sequel/connection_pool/C:/Program Files/logstash-6.3.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/sequel-5.10.0/lib/sequel/connection_pool/threaded.rb)
C_3a_.Program_20_Files.logstash_minus_6_dot_3_dot_2.vendor.bundle.jruby.$2_dot_3_dot_0.gems.sequel_minus_5_dot_10_dot_0.lib.sequel.connection_pool.threaded.hold(C:/Program Files/logstash-6.3.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/sequel-5.10.0/lib/sequel/connection_pool/threaded.rb:90)
C_3a_.Program_20_Files.logstash_minus_6_dot_3_dot_2.vendor.bundle.jruby.$2_dot_3_dot_0.gems.sequel_minus_5_dot_10_dot_0.lib.sequel.database.connecting.synchronize(C:/Program Files/logstash-6.3.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/sequel-5.10.0/lib/sequel/database/connecting.rb:270)
C_3a_.Program_20_Files.logstash_minus_6_dot_3_dot_2.vendor.bundle.jruby.$2_dot_3_dot_0.gems.sequel_minus_5_dot_10_dot_0.lib.sequel.database.connecting.test_connection(C:/Program Files/logstash-6.3.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/sequel-5.10.0/lib/sequel/database/connecting.rb:279)
C_3a_.Program_20_Files.logstash_minus_6_dot_3_dot_2.vendor.bundle.jruby.$2_dot_3_dot_0.gems.sequel_minus_5_dot_10_dot_0.lib.sequel.database.connecting.connect(C:/Program Files/logstash-6.3.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/sequel-5.10.0/lib/sequel/database/connecting.rb:58)
C_3a_.Program_20_Files.logstash_minus_6_dot_3_dot_2.vendor.bundle.jruby.$2_dot_3_dot_0.gems.sequel_minus_5_dot_10_dot_0.lib.sequel.core.connect(C:/Program Files/logstash-6.3.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/sequel-5.10.0/lib/sequel/core.rb:116)
C_3a_.Program_20_Files.logstash_minus_6_dot_3_dot_2.vendor.bundle.jruby.$2_dot_3_dot_0.gems.logstash_minus_input_minus_jdbc_minus_4_dot_3_dot_9.lib.logstash.plugin_mixins.jdbc.block in jdbc_connect(C:/Program Files/logstash-6.3.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/logstash-input-jdbc-4.3.9/lib/logstash/plugin_mixins/jdbc.rb:114)
org.jruby.RubyKernel.loop(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1292)
org.jruby.RubyKernel$INVOKER$s$0$0$loop.call(org/jruby/RubyKernel$INVOKER$s$0$0$loop.gen)
C_3a_.Program_20_Files.logstash_minus_6_dot_3_dot_2.vendor.bundle.jruby.$2_dot_3_dot_0.gems.logstash_minus_input_minus_jdbc_minus_4_dot_3_dot_9.lib.logstash.plugin_mixins.jdbc.jdbc_connect(C:/Program Files/logstash-6.3.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/logstash-input-jdbc-4.3.9/lib/logstash/plugin_mixins/jdbc.rb:111)
C_3a_.Program_20_Files.logstash_minus_6_dot_3_dot_2.vendor.bundle.jruby.$2_dot_3_dot_0.gems.logstash_minus_input_minus_jdbc_minus_4_dot_3_dot_9.lib.logstash.plugin_mixins.jdbc.RUBY$method$jdbc_connect$0$__VARARGS__(C_3a_/Program_20_Files/logstash_minus_6_dot_3_dot_2/vendor/bundle/jruby/$2_dot_3_dot_0/gems/logstash_minus_input_minus_jdbc_minus_4_dot_3_dot_9/lib/logstash/plugin_mixins/C:/Program Files/logstash-6.3.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/logstash-input-jdbc-4.3.9/lib/logstash/plugin_mixins/jdbc.rb)
C_3a_.Program_20_Files.logstash_minus_6_dot_3_dot_2.vendor.bundle.jruby.$2_dot_3_dot_0.gems.logstash_minus_input_minus_jdbc_minus_4_dot_3_dot_9.lib.logstash.plugin_mixins.jdbc.open_jdbc_connection(C:/Program Files/logstash-6.3.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/logstash-input-jdbc-4.3.9/lib/logstash/plugin_mixins/jdbc.rb:164)
C_3a_.Program_20_Files.logstash_minus_6_dot_3_dot_2.vendor.bundle.jruby.$2_dot_3_dot_0.gems.logstash_minus_input_minus_jdbc_minus_4_dot_3_dot_9.lib.logstash.plugin_mixins.jdbc.RUBY$method$open_jdbc_connection$0$__VARARGS__(C_3a_/Program_20_Files/logstash_minus_6_dot_3_dot_2/vendor/bundle/jruby/$2_dot_3_dot_0/gems/logstash_minus_input_minus_jdbc_minus_4_dot_3_dot_9/lib/logstash/plugin_mixins/C:/Program Files/logstash-6.3.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/logstash-input-jdbc-4.3.9/lib/logstash/plugin_mixins/jdbc.rb)
C_3a_.Program_20_Files.logstash_minus_6_dot_3_dot_2.vendor.bundle.jruby.$2_dot_3_dot_0.gems.logstash_minus_input_minus_jdbc_minus_4_dot_3_dot_9.lib.logstash.plugin_mixins.jdbc.execute_statement(C:/Program Files/logstash-6.3.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/logstash-input-jdbc-4.3.9/lib/logstash/plugin_mixins/jdbc.rb:220)
C_3a_.Program_20_Files.logstash_minus_6_dot_3_dot_2.vendor.bundle.jruby.$2_dot_3_dot_0.gems.logstash_minus_input_minus_jdbc_minus_4_dot_3_dot_9.lib.logstash.plugin_mixins.jdbc.RUBY$method$execute_statement$0$__VARARGS__(C_3a_/Program_20_Files/logstash_minus_6_dot_3_dot_2/vendor/bundle/jruby/$2_dot_3_dot_0/gems/logstash_minus_input_minus_jdbc_minus_4_dot_3_dot_9/lib/logstash/plugin_mixins/C:/Program Files/logstash-6.3.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/logstash-input-jdbc-4.3.9/lib/logstash/plugin_mixins/jdbc.rb)
C_3a_.Program_20_Files.logstash_minus_6_dot_3_dot_2.vendor.bundle.jruby.$2_dot_3_dot_0.gems.logstash_minus_input_minus_jdbc_minus_4_dot_3_dot_9.lib.logstash.inputs.jdbc.execute_query(C:/Program Files/logstash-6.3.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/logstash-input-jdbc-4.3.9/lib/logstash/inputs/jdbc.rb:264)
C_3a_.Program_20_Files.logstash_minus_6_dot_3_dot_2.vendor.bundle.jruby.$2_dot_3_dot_0.gems.logstash_minus_input_minus_jdbc_minus_4_dot_3_dot_9.lib.logstash.inputs.jdbc.RUBY$method$execute_query$0$__VARARGS__(C_3a_/Program_20_Files/logstash_minus_6_dot_3_dot_2/vendor/bundle/jruby/$2_dot_3_dot_0/gems/logstash_minus_input_minus_jdbc_minus_4_dot_3_dot_9/lib/logstash/inputs/C:/Program Files/logstash-6.3.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/logstash-input-jdbc-4.3.9/lib/logstash/inputs/jdbc.rb)
C_3a_.Program_20_Files.logstash_minus_6_dot_3_dot_2.vendor.bundle.jruby.$2_dot_3_dot_0.gems.logstash_minus_input_minus_jdbc_minus_4_dot_3_dot_9.lib.logstash.inputs.jdbc.run(C:/Program Files/logstash-6.3.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/logstash-input-jdbc-4.3.9/lib/logstash/inputs/jdbc.rb:250)
C_3a_.Program_20_Files.logstash_minus_6_dot_3_dot_2.vendor.bundle.jruby.$2_dot_3_dot_0.gems.logstash_minus_input_minus_jdbc_minus_4_dot_3_dot_9.lib.logstash.inputs.jdbc.RUBY$method$run$0$__VARARGS__(C_3a_/Program_20_Files/logstash_minus_6_dot_3_dot_2/vendor/bundle/jruby/$2_dot_3_dot_0/gems/logstash_minus_input_minus_jdbc_minus_4_dot_3_dot_9/lib/logstash/inputs/C:/Program Files/logstash-6.3.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/logstash-input-jdbc-4.3.9/lib/logstash/inputs/jdbc.rb)
C_3a_.Program_20_Files.logstash_minus_6_dot_3_dot_2.logstash_minus_core.lib.logstash.pipeline.inputworker(C:/Program Files/logstash-6.3.2/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:512)
C_3a_.Program_20_Files.logstash_minus_6_dot_3_dot_2.logstash_minus_core.lib.logstash.pipeline.RUBY$method$inputworker$0$__VARARGS__(C_3a_/Program_20_Files/logstash_minus_6_dot_3_dot_2/logstash_minus_core/lib/logstash/C:/Program Files/logstash-6.3.2/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb)
C_3a_.Program_20_Files.logstash_minus_6_dot_3_dot_2.logstash_minus_core.lib.logstash.pipeline.block in start_input(C:/Program Files/logstash-6.3.2/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:505)
org.jruby.RubyProc.call(org/jruby/RubyProc.java:289)
org.jruby.RubyProc.call(org/jruby/RubyProc.java:246)
```

sql.conf:

```
input {
  jdbc {
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?useSSL=false&amp;serverTimezone=GMT&amp;DatabaseName=test"
    jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"
    jdbc_driver_library => "C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\Connector J 8.0\mysql-connector-java-8.0.12.jar"
    jdbc_user => "test"
    jdbc_password => "test123"

    statement => "SELECT * FROM phones"
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
    index => "phones"
  }
}
```

Comment: The connection string in the exception looks like a Frankenstein of an SQL Server + MySQL connection string nor do the username and password match the one in your configuration. In other words, your `sql.conf` is not the one picked up while loading. Find out why.

Comment: Also, `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver` is the **new** driver name introduced in MySQL Connector/J 8, `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` is the **old** driver name (and still exists in Connector/J 8). Renaming that won't fix your problem, as your problem is an incorrect config.

Comment: "rename the actual mySQL connector ... should fix everything" - at the risk of breaking everything *else*..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewriting the whole connection string worked after a few tweaks. At the time of the issue a few drivers references I found within x-pack were referencing the wrong driver if memory serves and needed changing.